# How to return an array of partial matches in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to do something similar to the autocomplete widget in jQuery UI with userscore. I've tried using `_.where()`, but this only works if there's a complete match.

This works:

```
var people = [
    { id: 1, name: "Jimmy" },
    { id: 2, name: "Johnny" },
    { id: 3, name: "Susan" },
    { id: 4, name: "Tim" },
    { id: 5, name: "Betty" },
    { id: 6, name: "Ralph" }
];
var filteredPeople = _.where(people, { name: "Jimmy" });
```

But what I would like is something like this:

```
var filteredPeople = _.where(people, { name: "im" });   //Should return "Jimmy" and "Tim"
```

Is using `._where` not the correct approach? If not, what would be a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is using ._where not the correct approach?

Yes. [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) returns "*values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed*". This exact match is not what you want.

> What would be a better way to approach this?

Use the more general [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function:

```
var filteredPeople = _.filter(people, function(person) {
    return person.name.indexOf("im") > -1;
});
```

Of course, you can use something different from `indexOf`. If you wanted to use regular expressions, it might look like:

```
return /im/.test(person.name);
```

Answer (score 4):

in 2017 you can do:

**lodash**:

```
_.filter(people, p => _.includes(p.name, 'im'))
```

**es6**:

```
people.filter(p => p.name.includes('im'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `_.filter`:

```
_.filter(people, function(person) { return person.name.match(new RegExp('im')); });
```